# how to format below script in javascript

Tags: javascript, format

My current output format is

```
[{"label"=>"@mah", "value"=>"@mah"}, {"label"=>"@mahesh", "value"=>"@mahesh"}, {"label"=>"brand", "value"=>"brand"}]
```

But i want in this format :

```
[{"label":"@mah", "value":"@mah"}, {"label":"@mahesh", "value":"@mahesh"}, {"label":"brand", "value":"brand"}]
```

can any one please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a working example of what you have with your attempt(s) to get your expected output. Thank you.

Comment: add some code and explain the problem. show some effort what had you tried.

Comment: Do you want to replace `=>`s with `:`s in a **string**, briefly?

Comment: llooks like php. you may make a JSON string out of it.

Comment: yes i want to replace => into :  . that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Split and Join (Functional) Implementation:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

var str='[{"label"=>"@mah", "value"=>"@mah"}, {"label"=>"@mahesh", "value"=>"@mahesh"}, {"label"=>"brand", "value"=>"brand"}]';
console.log(str);

console.log(str.replaceAll("=>", ":"));
```